# 'CategoryDetail' object has no attribute '_state'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to get the properties by categories.

When I try to reach for example : http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/Berlin the following error comes:

> 'CategoryDetail' object has no attribute '_state'

What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

*`models.py`*

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Property(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    description = models.TextField()
    rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    bed_rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    land_size = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    living_size = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    build_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(to='Category', null=True, related_name='categories', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('properties:PropertyDetail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(
            self.title, self.build_year
        )

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField()


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('properties:CategoryDetail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})



    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

---

*`views.py`*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .filters import PropertyFilter

# Create your views here.

from django.views.generic import (
    TemplateView, DetailView, ListView
)

from .models import Property, Category

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'


class PropertyList(ListView):
    model = Property


class PropertyDetail(DetailView):
    model = Property


class CategoryList(ListView):
    model = Category


class CategoryDetail(ListView):
    queryset = Category.categories
    template_name = 'categorydetail.html'


def search(request):
    property_list = Property.objects.all()
    property_filter = PropertyFilter(request.GET, queryset=property_list)
    return render(request, 'prop_list.html', {'filter': property_filter})
```

---

*`urls.py`*

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import  (PropertyList, PropertyDetail, HomePage, CategoryList, CategoryDetail)

app_name = 'properties'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePage.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('categories', CategoryList.as_view(), name='categories'),
    path('category/<slug:slug>', CategoryDetail.as_view(), name='CategoryDetail'),
    path('properties', PropertyList.as_view(), name='PropertyList'),
    path('property/<slug:slug>', PropertyDetail.as_view(), name='PropertyDetail'),
]
```

---

project urls

```
"""config URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from realestate import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),
    path('', include('realestate.urls', namespace='properties')),
]
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290001/object-has-no-attribute-state

Comment: Looks like your problem is in defining view `queryset` param with `queryset = Category.categories`. This way you are getting manager, not queryset itself Try `queryset = Category.categories.all()`

Comment: What do you want `CategoryDetail` to display? I would expect it to use a `DetailView` to display details of a single category, but you are using a `ListView`.

Comment: in CategoryDetail in what to display a list of all properties related to the category.
For example all properties which have the category Berlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the `related_name` to `properties` as @cezar suggested, since it is used to get the related *properties* for a category.

```
category = models.ForeignKey(to='Category', null=True, related_name='categories', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,)
```

I suggest you use a `DetailView` for category,

```
class CategoryDetail(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'categorydetail.html'
```

Then you can use the reverse relationship to access the properties in the template:

```
{% for property in category.properties.all %}
```

If you really want to use a list view for `CategoryDetail`, then you need to override `get_queryset` and use the `slug`. For example you could do:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class PropertiesForCategory(ListView):
    template_name = 'categorydetail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug']
        return category.properties.all()
```

Then in the template you would loop through the queryset with:

```
{% for property in object_list %}
```

Comment: You can use `context_object_name` and eventually assign it a value `properties`. Then in the template you can do `{% for property in properties %}`, which looks more elegant and readable to me.

Comment: @cezar
thank you very much for that.
I would love to learn from that.
So basically in a Class Based or List view I cant use
queryset = category.properties.all()

the ".all()" isnt allowed there?

Comment: The problem with `queryset = category.properties.all()` isn't the `.all()` - it's that `category` isn't defined anywhere. With the `ListView` approach, you have to override `get_queryset` and fetch `category` first.

Answer (score 1):

Please adapt the following line in the class `Property`:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(to='Category', null=True, related_name='categories', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,)
```

to this:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(
    to='Category',
    null=True,
    related_name='properties',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
)
```

The change is in bold. The reason for the change is that you want to get *properties* for a given *Category*. Making a query like `Category.categories` is confusing for the reader.

The `related_name` which is now `properties` can be accessed from a `Category` object. The way how you do it in the class `CategoryDetail`:

```
queryset = Category.categories
```

even if adapted to:

```
queryset = Category.properties
```

can't work. It is because it would call the related descriptor `ReverseManyToOneDescriptor` which is of no use here.

You can call the properties for an object `Category`. An example would be:

```
Category.objects.get(pk=1).properties.all()
```

The first part `Category.objects.get(pk=1)` will return a single object `Category` and in the second part `properties.all()` you call the manager `properties` on the object `Category`. With the method `all()` you retrieve a QuerySet containing all `properties` for the given `Category` object.

Remember that using something like `Category.objects.all().properties.all()` won't work. `Category.objects.all()` will return a QuerySet which has no attribute `properties`.

With this in mind the best approach would be as suggested by @Alasdair to use `DetailView`. You want to **list** all *Properties* for a *Category* and that confuses you a little bit. However you're still displaying the **detail**s for a Category. Using a `DetailView` for the `Category` here is a much cleaner and nicer approach.

Having just simple:

```
class CategoryDetail(DetailView):
    model = Category
```

will do the job. The default template name will be `category_detail.html` and you don't need to specify it explicitly. Just be consistent with the other classes.

The internal logic of the detail view will retrieve a single object `Category` and in the template you can access the `properties` for this object:

```
{% for property in object.properties.all %}
    {{ property }}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of `object.properties.all` you can use `category.properties.all`, which is more verbose and improves the readability.

Should you wish to change that, do this for example:

```
class CategoryDetail(DetailView):
    model = Category
    context_object_name = 'ctgr'

{% for property in ctgr.properties.all %}
```

I hope this can bring you forward.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I tried it with ".all() before"
then I get this error in the terminal queryset = Category.properties.all()
AttributeError: 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: There was a comment from Alasdair, which is deleted, pointing out that you can't call the related manager on the class. I'll edit the answer later.

Comment: that you very much.
I tried also to put the ".all" in the template like {% for property in object_list.all %}
I still receive the same erroer

Comment: @RobertF. Thatt can't work. If you have an object you could do `{% for property in object.properties.all %}`. But here you have a queryset and can't do that.

Comment: @RobertF. I edited the answer and added explanation about the usage of the `related_name`. I hope that helps you to understand the underlying logic.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my model was just having an issue being called twice to do an action on a ForeignKey. Simply refetching the object before trying to reuse it fixed my issue.